# UIView added to a Table View from IB getting resized and not holding a fized size (XCode 6 | ios 8 | Non ARC code)

Tags: uitableview, uiview, xcode6, autolayout, tablefooterview

I need to set a tablefooterview for my UITableView. I added a UIView below the UITableViewCell of my UITableView which is a custom cell in the interface builder and set the height and width of the UIView as 44 and 400. The UIView is getting resized to a height of say 500 while running. Am sure am messing up with AutoLayouts. Am on ios 8 and xcode 6. Need to keep a fized height to the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a height and width constraint to the view. In the builder, you can select the view, click the "Add new constraints icon" (|-□-|), select width and height.